# Read date without timezone information

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

I receive datetime strings with no timezone qualifier in the format:

```
2014-01-30 07:48:25
```

I know that the strings are produced by a server in Florida. Is there a way using java.util or joda Date libs to specify that the date is from Florida then parse it with the appripriate UTC offset, depending on where it falls in the calendar for daylight savings time?

Comment: When you parse it, just make sure your parser's timezone is set to Florida's timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to the part of Florida following EST, you can set the timezone for `SimpleDateFormat` and set your TimeZone to EST.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
Date date = format.parse("2014-01-30 07:48:25");
```

Your parsed date now can be utilized by your default `TimeZone` of the system (or set it to your liking as we did in the first place).

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(date);
```

The output I get for your date offset to UTC:

```
Thu Jan 30 12:48:25 UTC 2014
```

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a "source timezone" to an instance of `SimpleDateFormat` and the to-be-parsed date string is then converted to your local/default timezone.

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York")
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
sdf.setTimeZone(getTimeZone(source));
```

Be careful when providing the time zone name. `TimeZone` will silently fail over to GMT if you pass in a string it does not understand as a timezone.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete previous answers. The same funcionality with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse("2014-01-30 07:48:25", DateTimeFormat
   .forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
   .withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York")));
System.out.println(dateTime);
System.out.println(dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC));
System.out.println(dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Madrid")));

---

2014-01-30T07:48:25.000-05:00
2014-01-30T12:48:25.000Z
2014-01-30T13:48:25.000+01:00
```

Comment: Nice answer, but that first line would be more clear if you broke it into two. Instantiate a "formatter" var ([`DateTimeFormatter`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)) on first line, then pass it on second line.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes, maybe better for readability. I think I'm a bit addicted to fluent APIs ;-).